# Julia packages are installed globally ("~/.julia/") instead specifically in the conda environment

Tags: julia, conda, virtualenv, mbedtls, conda-forge

I have created a separate conda environment for julia, Initially I installed julia with conda-forge but with that i was unable to install IJulia because there is an error in compiling MbedTLS, so I looked around and found out to install julia with juliaups, and it worked. But the packages i install in julia while in the conda environment the packages are installed globally, as in "~/.julia/", I want them to be installed in the conda environment directory (like when i install julia via conda-forge, the packages i install are installed in the environment directory but i can't use conda-forge becouse of "MbedTLS" issue). Can anyone help me with this.
Thanks"

I want the packages to be installed in the environment directory instead globally at the home directory

Comment: Do you want to use Julia inside of Python scripts? Or is there another reason why you installed it via Conda or want to have it in a Conda environment instead of installing it directly? Julia has its own environment system (Pkg.jl).

Comment: Most likely you look into `ENV["PTHON"]="/path/to/your/conda/python"; using Pkg; Pkg.build("Python")` But the answer will vary depending on what your setting is. Pls provide more information.

Comment: @maxxilian Using julia installed via conda-forge in a separate conda environment means using julia inside of python script? I only want to create a speparate conda julia environment for my current project because the package files (and it is tricky to clean up dumps and trash files) takes too much space and I have got limited space in my work system..

Comment: If you are not intending to solely use Julia from within Python, then I see no reason why you should use Conda to install and manage Julia. Julia comes with its own environment system that also arguably works better than Conda. So, I'd just install Julia in the normal way.

Comment: @maxxilian, I see, and can I manage packages separately in different julia environments? Can I also specify location for a new environment..? And I usually work with jupyter, so I have to install a new kernel on that environment so that I can access that environment from jupyter.
Sorry for too many questions, but please address them.

Comment: https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/